# How to autocomplete arguments in custom functions for Monaco?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, monaco-editor

I currently want to use a monaco editor with PHP and I want to expand it with autocompletion for the regular PHP functions as well as custom functions.

While the autocomplete for functions works fine on my early prototype, autocompleting the parameters does not work. See the fiddle for an example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/95aq6497/2/

Currently, only the function substr is provided as autocomplete and is working. However, the helper for parameters defined by registerSignatureHelpProvider does not work:

```
 monaco.languages.registerSignatureHelpProvider('php', {
provideSignatureHelp: (model, position, token) => {
  console.log('Signature Help');
  return {
    activeParameter: 0,
    activeSignature: 0,
    signatures: [{
      label: 'string substr(string $string, int $start [, int $length])',
      parameters: [
        {
          label: 'string $string',
          documentation: 'The input string. Must be one character or longer.'
        },
        {
          label: 'int $start',
          documentation: "If $start is non-negative, the returned string will start at the $start'th position in string, counting from zero. For instance, in the string 'abcdef', the character at position 0 is 'a', the character at position 2 is 'c', and so forth.\r\nIf $start is negative, the returned string will start at the $start'th character from the end of string. If $string is less than $start characters long, FALSE will be returned."
        },
        {
          label: 'int $length',
          documentation: 'If $length is given and is positive, the string returned will contain at most $length characters beginning from $start (depending on the length of $string) If $length is given and is negative, then that many characters will be omitted from the end of $string (after the start position has been calculated when a start is negative). If $start denotes the position of this truncation or beyond, FALSE will be returned. If $length is given and is 0, FALSE or NULL, an empty string will be returned. If $length is omitted, the substring starting from $start until the end of the string will be returned.'
        }
      ]
    }]
  };
}
```

});

The function is not even executing, as the console.log does not trigger at all. What am I missing? Expanding javascript similarly by a function worked fine like this, but it's not working for PHP, so what's different here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you didn't provide `signatureHelpTriggerCharacters` option:

```
monaco.languages.registerSignatureHelpProvider('php', {
  signatureHelpTriggerCharacters: ['(', ','],  <==================== this one
  provideSignatureHelp: (model, position, token) => {
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hec12da1/

To implement `provideSignatureHelp` function I would suggest you to take a look at typescript version

https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-typescript/blob/7027f0b4ba56fc0df136fb41791aa27e8c25ef54/src/languageFeatures.ts#L262